# Javascript new Date(); returns 1970-01-01 in Shopify Function

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-app

I am working on a Shopify Function in which today's date is compared to another date.

When I run `new Date();` to get today's date, it returns "1970-01-01"

I know this is epoch time, but the issue I am having is everyone says `new Date();` is supposed to return today's date, but it isn't working for me. Is this an issue with how Shopify extensions handle dateTime parsing, or is there some other way I am supposed to get today's date.

Comment: Maybe they monkey patched it who knows. Try this `new Date(Date.now())` what does it return?

Comment: Javascripts Date uses the system date, see if you've an issue on your machine with the date sync. if running new date in the console returns epoch them it cant read your system date otherwise it'll print out the same date that the system is set to.

Comment: @danielRICADO The issue is this is for a Shopify app. When developing an app, it runs on their servers, not on your local system, you just push up changes to their dev environment. That's why I was wondering if it might have something to do with how Shopify handles Javascript.

Comment: ah one of those. but you're looking at it on a browser? javascript date is looking for the system Date of the users machine. But if there's some SSR thing going on it's maybe possible that needs raising with shopify or they require some special way of dealing with dates.

Comment: @danielRICADO It's more of a nodeJS backend thing, so it's not interacting with the browser. I'll have to check with Shopify to see if there is something I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution for this that is specifically related to Shopify.
I am creating an extension for Shopify using the Storefront API. To get the current date (dateTime functionality has unfortunately not been added as of writing this answer) you need to add the following to your .graphql query:

```
  shop {
    localTime {
      date
    }
  }
```

Here is a link to the documentation:

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/functions/reference/cart-checkout-validation/graphql/common-objects/shop